# How to gsub a string with a concatenated value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gsub

I need to change the value of a parameter (OFFSET=) by adding 20 to its value. So instead of having OFFSET=0 I get OFFSET=20. Now, I can't be sure that the value for OFFSET is equal to 0, so I need to extract it. Here is what I have tried:

```
aNumber  = "myValue=20".match(/myValue=(\d+)/)[1].to_i
bString  = "OFFSET=#{aNumber}"
newValue = bString.gsub(/OFFSET=#{aNumber}/, "OFFSET=#{aNumber + 20}")
```

Now, to use `#{}` I obviously need a string with `""`, which I can't use together with `.gsub()` or `.match()`. Right now I am not able to gsub because it can't get the value of `aNumber`. How can that be done?

Comment: it would be super helpful if you put examples of what you want to achieve instead of talking about what you can or can't do.

Comment: I ran the above commands and I got the output `OFFSET=40`. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, and it works now - hasn't before for some strange reason. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gsub with a block:

```
x = "myValue=20"
p x.gsub(/\d+/){|x| x.to_i + 20} # => myValue=20
```

or if you have a longer string and only want to change myValue:

```
x = "firstValue=10, myValue=20, otherValue=30"
p x.gsub(/(?<=myValue=)(\d+)/){|x|  x.to_i + 20} # => firstValue=10, myValue=40, otherValue=30
```